# I get an error with trying to parse the integer from the textfile

Tags: c#, text-files, system.io.file

I'm getting errors when I try to "login" to this. Its a school project and I know its simple, I just need it to function properly, any help is appreciated. Try to ignore obviously inefficient code.

```
   class UserVariables
        {
            public static int avatarC;
            public static int colourC;
            public static string userNameC;
            public static string passWordC;
            public static int highScoreC;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bool success = false;

                string UsernameTXT = "userName.txt";
                string PasswordTXT = "userPass.txt";
                string ColourTXT = "userColour.txt";
                string AvatarTXT = "userAvatar.txt";
                string ScoreTXT = "userScore.txt";

                using (StreamReader user_Login = new StreamReader(UsernameTXT))
                {
                    using (StreamReader pass_Login = new StreamReader(PasswordTXT))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader colour_Login = new StreamReader(ColourTXT))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader avatar_Login = new StreamReader(AvatarTXT))
                            {
                                using (StreamReader score_login = new StreamReader(ScoreTXT))
                                {
                                    var lineCount = File.ReadLines(UsernameTXT).Count();
                                    string userRead;
                                    string passRead;
                                    string colourRead;
                                    string avatarRead;
                                    string scoreRead;

                                    for (int a = 0; a < lineCount; a++)
                                    {
                                        userRead = user_Login.ReadLine();
                                        passRead = pass_Login.ReadLine();
                                        colourRead = user_Login.ReadLine();
                                        avatarRead = pass_Login.ReadLine();
                                        scoreRead = user_Login.ReadLine();

                                        if ((textBox1.Text == userRead) && (textBox2.Text == passRead))
                                        {
                                            UserVariables.userNameC = textBox1.Text;
                                            UserVariables.passWordC = textBox2.Text;

                                            UserVariables.colourC = int.Parse(colourRead);
                                            // Theres a problem with this line.

                                            UserVariables.avatarC = int.Parse(avatarRead);
                                            UserVariables.highScoreC = int.Parse(scoreRead);
                                            MessageBox.Show("Login successful!",
                                                "Success");

                                            success = true;

                                            new Menus().Show();

                                            this.Hide();

                                            MessageBox.Show("Hi, " + UserVariables.userNameC + "!");
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (success == false)
                                    {
                                        label1.Show();

                                        MessageBox.Show("Login was unsuccessful.",
                                            "Error");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to describe the errors ... What are the contents of the strings you attempt to parse?

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format" but im sure its a number, simple ones just like 2 or 3

Comment: That error indicates otherwise, What does it look like exactly?

Comment: Set a break point at the offending line and check the value in the debugger.

Comment: well im using a  try catch around it but its just a huge error that says "Input string was not in a correct format" and after that it starts talking giberish, like intParse decimalboolean and stuff like that

Comment: find out what value colourRead has when you try to parse it to an int.  Then find out why it's not what you wanted.  That's debugging

Comment: thanks dirk its reading the wrong file i cant remeber changing this but its the section above that says

Comment: userRead = user_Login.ReadLine();
                                        passRead = pass_Login.ReadLine();
                                        colourRead = user_Login.ReadLine();
                                        avatarRead = pass_Login.ReadLine();
                                        scoreRead = user_Login.ReadLine();

Comment: Did you mean to read from the other files? Your code has you reading only from user_Login and pass_Login.

Comment: @AdamHiggins That "gibberish" is called a stack trace. If you want to learn to program, you're going to need to learn how to read it. It's telling you where the error came from, and what path your program took to get to it. Look closely, and you'll see it's naming functions, classes and files from your code. That's a list of the steps your program went through to get to the error. It's written by unwinding back *out* from the place the error occurred, so read from the bottom upwards to get it in chronological order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is "Input string was not in a correct format", which tells me that at least one value of colourRead is not an integer value.  int.Parse ignores whitespace, so it isn't a matter of formatting.  It cannot be a simple integer value and has to contain another character like "2a", "2.0", "1,000", etc.

To figure out exactly which value, you can create a breakpoint or watch and start debugging, or you can use int.TryParse

Try this instead

```
if(!int.TryParse(colourRead, out UserVariables.colourC))
{
    MessageBox.Show(colourRead);
}
// Theres a problem with this line.
```

It will likely pop up a window telling you exactly what value it is trying to turn into an int.

---

Also, I forsee problems with the way you are reading the files.  You get the number of lines in userTXT by doing this:

```
 var lineCount = File.ReadLines(UsernameTXT).Count();
```

Which will read the entire file contents, and count up how many lines exist.  That's not a great way of doing this, but it should be functional as long as the files aren't too long.

You are then stepping through every line in this file, but reading 3 lines for every iteration of the for loop

```
userRead = user_Login.ReadLine();
...
colourRead = user_Login.ReadLine();
...
scoreRead = user_Login.ReadLine();
```

You will run out of lines to read from your file before the for loop completes.

Comment: You may mean `int.TryParse()` (which will require an `out` parameter); I'm pretty sure `int.Parse()` throws on an unparseable value. Which is of course the problem here.

Comment: Yes, I meant int.TryParse.  Fixing it now.